# Probability density function of $(X, Y + t X)$ when $(X, Y)$ is normally distributed

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose we have two random variables, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma^2)$ and $(X, Y)$ has a bivariate normal distribution. In addition, the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$ is $t$.

I am trying to compute the joint PDF of $(X, Y + t X)$, but I am not sure how to start.

I think that I need to find the PDF of $Y + t X$ first. Any ideas are more than welcome.

Edit: Added the correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: 1) You have not yet specified the full joint distribution of $(X,Y)$; you either need to tell us that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, or specify the covariance (or correlation) between $X$ and $Y$. 2) $(X,Y+tX)$ will also be bivariate normal (you need to justify why), so all you need to do is write down the two means, two variances, and the covariance (or correlation).

Comment: @angryavian It has since been added that $\rho(X,Y)=t$.